# any api in c to alter route table in linux

Tags: c, routes

There is any api in c which can set multicast ip address in route table in linux.

like 
through command it can be like this

ip route add multicast  dev

there is any c api which will same as above command is doing.

thanks in advance

Comment: Find the source of the command, and you'll know.  Or even try running it under strace.

Comment: Just `strace` (or perhaps also `ltrace`) your `ip route` command and you'll find it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general strategy for answering questions of this form is `strace`. Run

```
strace ip route add multicast dev
```

or similar and look at what syscalls it performs. I suspect it's using "netlink" which is an arcane Linux-specific protocol for communicating with the kernel network system via a special type of socket.

Rather than trying to implement netlink protocol in your application, I think it would make more sense to invoke the necessary `ip route` command via `posix_spawn` (or legacy `fork` + `execve`).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the documentation for *rtnetlink*

This is the userspace api to interact with the kernel routing rules.